# How to set fitetype depends on current directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I`m using Vim I would like to set my filetype like below

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *_controller.rb set ft=rails syntax=ruby
```

but depends on current file directory example if I open `/code/project/app/model/somefile.rb` I would like to set `filetype` as `model`

For now I`m using `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead */app/models/*.rb set ft=model syntax=ruby`

But maybe is better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead */model/*.rb set ft=model
```